# Download image in a URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, qr-code

I have a QR in a URL

I want to click a button and download the image of the QR in the URL

URL: [https://quickchart.io/qr?text=http://tapo.app&dark=000&light=fff&ecLevel=H&margin=1&size=500¢erImageSizeRatio=0.4¢erImageUrl=https://app.tapo.app/Logo-Big.png](https://quickchart.io/qr?text=http://tapo.app&dark=000&light=fff&ecLevel=H&margin=1&size=500%C2%A2erImageSizeRatio=0.4%C2%A2erImageUrl=https://app.tapo.app/Logo-Big.png)

is it possible using PHP or Javascript?

I havent figured it out.

Comment: What do you mean by downloading an image in a URL? Do you mean download the image that is loaded from the URL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `fetch` to get the content as a blob, then create an `<a>` element with the download attribute. Clicking on the anchor will download the image.

```js
fetch('https://quickchart.io/qr?text=http://tapo.app&dark=000&light=fff&ecLevel=H&margin=1&size=500%C2%A2erImageSizeRatio=0.4%C2%A2erImageUrl=https://app.tapo.app/Logo-Big.png').then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'Image.png';
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

Comment: Something like This? 

<html>
<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="descarga();">Descargar</a>
<script>
function descarga(){
fetch('https://quickchart.io/qr?text=http://tapo.app&dark=000&light=fff&ecLevel=H&margin=1&size=500%C2%A2erImageSizeRatio=0.4%C2%A2erImageUrl=https://app.tapo.app/Logo-Big.png').then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'Image.png';
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user3521690 Sure, that looks fine.